# (Python) Pygame: render text with special characters ( × ÷ π etc)

Tags: python, special-characters, pygame

This might be a very nooberious question (or it may not), but here it is. I am tying to display special characters on screen (specifically the multiplication symbol '×') using pygame.

The code works like this:

```
label = helvetica.render("text here", 1, (r, g, b))
window.blit(label, (x, y))
```

What do I have to put in "text here" in order for this to work? Or is there another way around this?

I have attempted to muck around with the text encoding, using UTF-8 etc... but I hardly know anything about it and I haven't had any success.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Do you get any errors when you start up your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u'×'` should be enough.  In case it isn’t, add an [encoding definition](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for UTF-8 and save the file as such (without BOM!)  In case it still isn’t, this may be a PyGame problem.